# Installing package dependencies in Atom

Tags: npm, atom-editor

I've added the following into my `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "linter": "1.11.4"
}
```

But how do I actually get this dependency installed?

Comment: how did you get on with this, have you managed to get up and running with package development?

Comment: worked a charm, many thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After you have updated your `packages.json` and saved the file you can install the dependencies by running `Update Package Dependencies: Update`:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command Palette.
2. Type <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> which should select `Update Package Dependencies: Update`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Update Package Dependencies: Update]

If you are going to be doing a lot of this you can take it a step further and add a keybinding:

```
'atom-workspace':
  'ctrl-alt-shift-u': 'update-package-dependencies:update'
```

Comment: It **is** handled by Atom or APM automatically when you install a package from the package library dependencies are updated as part of the installation.

Comment: is there a way to do this offline\manually? Where can one find the files to download?

Comment: @RichardSlater, do I understand correctly that therefore I would .gitignore the created `node_modules` directory for publishing a package, because it is automatically created on installation?

Comment: In my experience, it's usual practice to exclude `node_modules` from source control as including it means checking all your dependant packages, binaries, etc. Not having it when you first check out a project and having to run `npm update` places significantly less burdon on Git and eliminates issues with merge conflicts in `node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

You install your package then Atom/npm take care of installing the dependencies.

https://discuss.atom.io/t/load-developing-package/2554/4

When you start Atom it loads packages from various directories. When you open it in developer mode it loads additional packages from `~/.atom/dev/packages`, so the first thing to do is to move/symlink your package to that directory.

Then you can go to your new package directory and run `atom -d .` to create a new atom window in developer mode and automatically add your package as a project directory.

Then you can run `apm install` to update your dependencies.

Comment: I'm developing a package, so not sure what you mean by install?